# How do I read letters in a text file in C?

Tags: c, fopen, scanf

I use the `fopen` code in `C` to read a text file. Then i use the `fscan` code to check for an integer number in that file that should be 1<= N <=5.

What I want is when the text file has letters inside it to show me a warning message that the file has at least one letter inside. But if it hasn't to procced to another code.

How can I do that? **I want to place the code after the `fscanf` command and before the `if`**

Here is the code

```
FILE * fp;                                                        //declare fp as a "fopen" command.    
fp = fopen ("xxx.txt", "r");                                      // opening the file "xxx.txt"
if (fp == NULL)                                                   // error here if there was a problem!
{
    printf("Opening 'xxx.txt file failed: %s\n",strerror(errno)); // No such file or directory
    getchar();                                                    // wait the user press a key
    return 0;                                                     // returning an int of 0, exit the program
}
else                                                              // if everything works.....
{
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&num);                                         // here goes the fscanf() command
    if(num<1 || num>5)                                            // set restrictions to integer 
    {
        printf("The number must be 1<= N <= 5",strerror(errno));  // error with the integer number
        getchar();                                                // wait the user press a key
        return 0;                                                 // returning an int of 0, exit the program
    }               
    else                                                          // if everything works.....
    {
        // some code here                   
    }
}
```

Comment: First: check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: `fopen` and `fscanf` are not *codes* but *library functions*. You should read documentation of [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) & [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html) -and of every other function you are using- and you should test their return value. Also, compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and use the debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: What does your file contain? Will it have some character followed by number followed by charachters or just number? Question is ambiguous.

Comment: Also consider dumping `scanf()` and reading data from the file with `fgets()`.

Comment: What good comes, on returning `0` for failure for opening file and then if the condition is not satisfied?

Comment: I have only numbers! That is why if  there is a letter there should I get an error message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inserted after scanning for num should read the rest of the file and report if a letter is found and return 1. It first gets the position in the file so you can return to that spot later and continue reading the file for integers.  If a letter is found, it returns 1. If no letters are found it resets the file position back to where it was after scanning num.

```
int readch = 0;
long int filepos = 0L;
filepos = ftell ( fp); // get the file position                                                                   
while ( ( readch = fgetc ( fp)) != EOF) { // read each character of the file                                      
    if ( isalpha ( readch)) { // check each character to see if it is a letter                                    
        printf ( "File contains letters\n");
        fclose ( fp);
        return 1;
    }
}
fseek ( fp, filepos, SEEK_SET); // move file position back to where it was after reading num
```